# Insist on a new filename

Tags: code-golf, file-system, interactive

At runtime, keep prompting for *a line of input* until the user input is **not** the name of an existing file or directory or other file system item, relative to the current working directory. Then return/print that last inputted filename. You may assume that all user inputs will be valid filenames.

#### Pseudo-code 1

```
myform = new form("GUI")
myform.mytxt = new editfield("")
myform.ok = new button("OK")
repeat
  waitfor(myform.ok,"click")
until not filesystem.exists(myform.mytxt.content)
return(myform.mytxt.content)
```

#### Pseudo-code 2

```
LET TEXT = "."
WHILE HASFILE(TEXT) DO
  TEXT = PROMPT("")
ENDWHILE
RETURN TEXT
```

#### Examples of user input which will cause re-prompting when on TIO:

```
.
..
.env.tio
/
/bin/[
/lost+found
```

#### Examples of user input which will return when on TIO:

```
...
env.tio
../../bin/]
/lost/found
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to code golf here and can't seem to find any information on what counts as a solution.  Do I need to include the main() function for languages that require it in a program, or can that be part of the header? Can import statements be a part of the header in TIO, or do they need to be part of the code and count against the byte count? For example, I have this solution: https://goo.gl/8RWNgu but not sure if it the bytes would be legitimate.

Comment: @Makotosan [Both functions and full programs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) are fine, although in the case of functions they need to be reusable. Imports generally need to be included in the byte count.

Answer (score 7):

### Batch, 37 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@if exist %s% %0
@echo %s%
```

(For some reason current Windows 10 `CMD.EXE` corrupts the title when it executes the `%0`.)

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, <s>33</s> 28 bytes

```
f:=Input[]/._?FileExistsQ:>f
```

This assumes Mathematica's notebook environment where we can query input from the user with `Input[]`. The user input should be [an actual string literal](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7634/8478), so e.g. `"ab/cd.ef"` instead of just `ab/cd.ef`. The upside is that the input can be an arbitrary Mathematica expression that computes the input string.

This defines a symbol `f` which, when evaluated performs the required computation and ultimately evaluates to the first non-existent user input. It's essentially a nullary function, where we don't have to include `...[]` to call it.

We can also save a bunch of bytes over a traditional `If` expression by making use of the pattern substitution operator `/.`.

Comment: This fails if the user inputs the same thing twice

Comment: @Mathe172 Good catch, too bad, then I'll have to go with the boring loop.

Comment: Turns out I don't, and it's even a byte shorter. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ln`, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [@DomHastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -ln
-e||1/!say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcoxCoAwDEDRPbdwliY6eAxP4FAqRizUtNiqCJ7d6CL87f3EW@hUDd93S1V2lyoCfrEcWHwEAhq90AAUYi71HHeZ4MeysE0bH/Z0WYqdfWBxKwPCE9M3SFYTRE3fYdtg8wI)

Comment: I think `-e` works without specifying `$_`, might not work for some cases though I guess...

Comment: @DomHastings Should work in all cases. It's documented that $_ is used when there is no argument to -e.

Comment: @DomHastings Thanks.For some reason I thought `-e` was an exception but of course it isn't

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 29

```bash
read f
[ -e $f ]&&$0||echo $f
```

Comment: [Why doesn't this work?](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyg1MUUhjStaQTdVQSVNIVZNTcWgpiY1OSMfyP3/Xz8pM49LPyk1FQA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám I'm not sure why it doesn't work in TIO.  Suffice to say if you save it as a script file and run it, I think it works as expected

Comment: @Adám [This](https://tio.run/##RYw5DoAgEAB7X7GisTG6vsCPiAXHEigEA5pY8HfUwthNZpKRItlS9uj8YYA1NZ4ponQe5RO4jyQ0GO4XGAh4a2DtOt5OOZOy4RUMZthEdGJMtlJ2Cxr66zcjfljKu61QEt0) works, the problem you had was that the program was trying to call `.code.tio` which contains the body of the script, but no information on how to run it. I'm not sure if there is a nice way to work around the shebang or this script needing to be in your path, though.

Comment: You can get around both (at the cost of two bytes) by changing `$0` to `. $0`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyg1MUUhjStaQTdVQSVNIVZNTU9BxaCmJjU5Ix8o8P@/flJmHpd@UmoqAA). Since `.` uses relative path names and the current shell.

Comment: What does it think of `*` as input?

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell 2 (through 6), 35 bytes

```
while(Test-Path($x=Read-Host)){};$x
```

`Read-Host` waits for input (if given a string as a parameter, uses the string as a prompt). If the provided input is a filename (or folder name) for one that exists, `Test-Path` returns `$true`, and the do-nothing block `{}` executes, and it re-prompts for input. If `Test-Path` returns `$false` because the input is not an extant file or folder, the do-nothing block does not execute, and the input name is printed.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You don't need the semi-colon after the {} to save a byte.

Comment: @Veskah - I did in PS2, and it doesn't break PS3+

Comment: Ah, my bad. Didn't test it in 2.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 62 bytes

```c
main(){char b[99];while(scanf("%s",b)&&!access(b,0));puts(b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6OSOxSCEp2tIy1ro8IzMnVaM4OTEvTUNJtVhJJ0lTTU0xMTk5tbhYI0nHQFPTuqC0BMjUtK79/1@PSw@IUvPK9Eoy87n0ufSTMvP0o4GCelz6OfnFJdpp@aV5KRC2PoQNUw0A)

```c
main(){
    char b[99]; // Declare buffer b
    while (scanf("%s",b)&&!access(b,0));    // Take one line of input, and test if file is accessible (exists)
    puts (b);   // If doesn't exist, loop ends and print file
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can use `while(gets(b),!access(b,0));` to save 7 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
import glob
s="."
while glob.glob(s):s=input()
print(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYm7DoAgDAD3foVxgsEyuJnwMyREm2hLoD74ekSTyw13qeomPLdGR5Ksw7pLgOJHHOHeaI9/wE@m2KV44nSqsZAysfbUGgJ2Il@oJODABWJgmeJDRSHU2P8L)

-4 bytes thanks to ManfP
-6 bytes thanks to Rick Rongen

Comment: @Adám terrible misinterpretation, sorry

Comment: You could replace the first `input()` with `"."`

Comment: `import os` and `os.path.exists` is three bytes shorter.

Comment: [Rick Rongen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79003/rick-rongen) suggested `import glob` and `while glob.glob(s):...` in an edit.

Comment: @MartinEnder thanks for telling me :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks; already got it down below -3 with another suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
import System.Directory
f=do x<-getLine;b<-doesPathExist x;last$pure x:[f|b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxDoIwFEX3fsUb3AztLrDpxmDCSBwKfZXG0kfahymJ/17Fm7Ockzvr9ELvS3HLSpGh3xPjIq8u4sQUd2FbQ5Cb6oncuYD12FSGMN01z7fsEkOuvU58WreIkC@D/YyPsmgXoAVDAn6LmKCpwP5l3bjn2IWjFinkDwxvyY6EEmp0QQ1CeUp8trQFI7SQExk8Dl8)

Returns `IO x` where `x` is the inputted name of the file that does not exist.

### Ungolfed

```hs
import System.Directory

insist = do { file <- getLine;
              exists <- doesPathExist file;
              if exists then insist else pure file }
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 40 bytes

```
tryfor)io.open(s=io.read())catchprint(s)
```

In true funky style, this uses keywords jammed against eachother, unmatching brackets and implicit keywords. Cleaned up, this looks like:

```
try{
    while(true){
        s = io.read()
        io.open(s)
    }
}catch(e){
    print(s)
}
```

## Breakdown

```
try                                     // Try statement, this one is expected to fail.
   for)                                 // for) is a for loop with no arguments, which is functionally equivilent to a while(true) loop, much like for(;;)
       io.open(                         // Try to open a file relative to the CWD. If this fails to find a file, it will throw an error and escape the try/catch
               s=io.read()              // Read a line from STDIN and store it as s, this will still pass it to the arguments of the call.
                          )
                           catch        // When io.open fails
                                print(s)// Print out the last entered line.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>66</s> 51 bytes

```
while((s=readline())%in%list.files(a=T)){};print(s)
```

*-15 bytes thanks to plannapus*

Runs a potentially infinite loop, where on each iteration

1. A single line of user input is stored in the variable `s`
2. We check if the input is in the list of filenames for the working directory (the `a=T` option for `list.files()` must be used to pick up things like `..`)
3. If `s` is in that list, we go to the next iteration; if not, we break the loop and print `s`.

Comment: How about shortening it to `while((s=readline())%in%list.files(a=T)){};print(s)`?

Comment: @plannapus Great idea! Incorporated.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I didn't think of it right away but functions `list.files` and `dir` are synonyms, so you can replace it with `dir` here.

Comment: you could also replace `readline()` with `scan(,'')`

Comment: And `print` with `cat`

Comment: 32 bytes: `while((s=scan(,''))%in%dir())t;s`

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 101 bytes

```cs
()=>{var s="";try{for(;;System.IO.File.GetAttributes(s=System.Console.ReadLine()));}catch{}return s;}
```

For each of the 4 valid return values:

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSgQxDIbvfYqwpw5i@wB1FkRYERRBBQ/iodvJaGFsockMLKXPPmbXXQw/OeT/Pkig65ALrmHyRPCGxKCqAiD2HAMsOQ7w5GPSnRwryJJ5PRDjj9nNKdwQl5i@tjBCD6vu@m1dfAHqNxvH5VDHXLRzZ@Hh2ezihOYe@ZbF28@MpKk/13c5UZb6Bf3wGBPqrutcC57Dd20FeS4JyLVVPnDq/42L9l4i48kbxTwSTbXVKCPBtBiOWVll9zHZD2WnTHw15jkNAhh1AYyxkiPz@cfYE/ML) (returns '...')
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSgMxEIbveYqhp4Ri8gBxCyJUBEVoBQ/SQ5qd1cCaQGZ2oYQ8@5rWFoefOcw3H/ye7nzKuPjREcE7EoMoAoDYcfAwp9DDqwtRqnYs0Fab/YkYf/R2iv6eOIf4tYEBOlik6jZldhmoW60s51MZUpbWXoXnN70NI@on5Adu3nFiJEndFT@mSKnhHbr@JUSUSilbvWP/XWpGnnIEsnVpDaz4r3HTPnJgvHhDM88fVdRFC92CcdYckjDCHEM0n8KMiXg9pCn24ga1Ni1nfvjj5sJ/AQ) (returns 'env.tio')
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSgQxEETv@YpmTxnE5APiLIiwIiiCCh7EQzbTswbGBNI9A0vIt4@964pN0YeqelCBrkMuuIbJE8EbEoOqCoDYcwyw5DjAk49Jd2JWkCf3eiTGb7ObU7ghLjEdtjBCD6vu@m1dfAHqNxvH5VjHXLRzF@Dh2ezihOYe@ZaF28@MpKm/xHc5UZb4Bf3wGBPqrutcC57DV20FeS4JyLVVFjj1P@MPey@R8cyNQp4aTbXVKCPCtBiOWVll9zHZD2WnTHw15jkNUrCik//569uz/wM) (returns '../..bin/])
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BagMxDETv/gqRk02p/QHOBkohJdBSaAI99OR4talhY4OlXQjG375x05QKIYYZPRhPjz5lXPzoiOCAxCCKACB2HDzMKfTw5kKUqpkF2mmzvxDjWW@n6NfEOcTTBgboYJGq25TZZaButbKcL2VIWVp7B3bvehtG1C/IT9y448RIkrp7/JwipRZ/oOtfQ0SplLLVO/bfpWbkKUcgW5fWwIr/Gn/YZw6MN25o5M9HFXXRQrfFOGsOSRhhjiGaL2HGRPwwpCn2v9rc9BU) (returns '/lost/found)

## Ungolfed

```cs
() =>
{
    var s = "";
    try
    {
        for(;; System.IO.File.GetAttributes(s = System.Console.ReadLine()));
    }
    catch {}
    return s;
}
```

### Explanation

relies on the fact that File.GetAttributes() throws an exception if file system object specified in its argument doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell 3.0, 75 bytes

```
$x=1;while($x){$i=Read-Host;$x=Test-Path("$PSScriptRoot\$i")};Write-Host $i
```

First attempt; I'm sure there are a few optimizations I could make.

A slightly more readable form:

```
$x=1;                                                                       # Make sure we enter our while loop.
     while($x){                                                             # While we keep getting file names,                   
               $i=Read-Host;                                                # Get input from the user
                            $x=Test-Path("$PSScriptRoot\$i")};              # Combine our path with the user input, and see if it already exists.
                                                              Write-Host $i # Return the final (valid) file name.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work even without ``$PSScriptRoot\``?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A few quick golfs -- you can use a `for` loop instead, which allows you to move the initialization into the loop constructor `for($x=1;$x){...}`. Secondly, you can get rid of the `Write-Host` since there's an implicit `Write-Output` at program completion for anything left on the pipeline, so just leaving `$i` there will suffice.

Comment: See my solution below; I've halved your byte count.

Comment: @Adám: Maybe! I hadn't actually considered that. :P

AdmBorkBork Thank you! I spent a long time lurking. Those are good ideas; the implicit output didn't even cross my mind...

Answer (score 2):

## Java 9, 87 bytes

```
v->{String s;for(;new java.io.File(s=System.console().readLine()).exists(););return s;}
```

### Ungolfed

[TIO's JVM apparently has no system `Console`](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwEETROpxiSlyEPsoZqCijFBtjIRPjtdgFKYo4u7MK1Ujz30w7XbmEPI/vW60@kQh6ihnfBijbK0UPUVKbneOIxVo76Brz9HiC1kncnwLDRzQsHW/aFcuazJ2X5yycQuvc3eTRHJdafw), so it's not testable there (see [`System.console()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console--)).

```
import java.util.function.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Void,String> f =


v->{
  String s;
  for(;new java.io.File(s=System.console().readLine()).exists(););
  return s;
}


;
    System.out.println(f.apply(null));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>158</s> 118 bytes

```javascript
require('readline').createInterface({input:process.stdin}).on('line',s=>require('fs').existsSync(s)||--console.log(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DgIhEIR7XuQgCvQm2ltbWnGwpxiye7LcxZ/z2REtTJxMJpNJvrm42bHPcSwaKUCtGa5TzCC7DC6kiNAp41svsMcCeXAe5DPiOJXNmMkDs@ESIr6UIZTdl1jzdvf7Gbg9wC1y4cMdvWS1LFp7QqYEJtGpLapWI0wz4GxKJGGF7SPao7CJuKwGmjCIPrmz/oR4fCX@mTc)

Credit to @ConorO'Brien for coming up with shorter version. Inlined objects instead of using consts and utilizing error exit condition instead of explicitly exiting.

Comment: Nice answer so far, but there's room for potential. You can golf this approach in a few ways: you can omit both `const`, and you can also replace each variable with it's definition. Then, instead of using `s=>{if(...){...}}`, you could use `s=>require('fs').existsSync(s)||process.exit(console.log(s))`. Additionally, you can exit with an error, so you can write the lambda as `s=>require('fs').existsSync(s)||--console.log(s)`. [Try it online!](https://goo.gl/ZDEAs2)

Comment: Great ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>100</s> 94 bytes

```
import System.IO,System.File
Start w#(s,w)=evalIO getLine w
#(b,w)=fileExists s w
|b=Start w=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoNAEATvvmLRiwH1B96SgCAY8AWjGc3C7K44E42Qt2digrfuqu6eELy6cH8SGgfWq3VTmMW0Gwu6omqyI10tYdQK7G5NUs7WU4kLUNWYEaW2Hs0aJWn348M@vbwsCxve6bsrj1/JqgX6pRAboviBRCH@9APByJp3mle1njcPzvb8LzcCGcLsvg)

**single-expression version:**

```
import System.IO,System.File
Start w=(\(s,v)=(\(b,w)|b=Start w=s)(fileExists s v))(evalIO getLine w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwEEX3PUXoKoHaG3SnQqFQoVs3aZ3WwCSRzpha8OyOVXT13@P9AcEG8fFyR1DeuiDO3@LMqluJwZd1W/zo6BCyju3WlkqfNRXJfLYvFvPsq38ho8fteXg4YlKkkjEaksW6VRNw4wKoxYiUEFLJLmb5FRBj/hpGtBPJrpdd3ch@Dda7gb5yQstjnP0b)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
{⍞}⍣{~⎕NEXISTS⍺}⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBNWPeufVPupdXF33qG@qn2uEZ3BI8KPeXUChNVx6XHpAlJpXpleSmc@lz6WflJmnH82ln5NfXKKdll@al8IFkyzJSI0vKEotiy9PLM4riU/LzEnNS8xNBQA)

Comment: Returns the *second* non-existing input, (`the_prev_wasnt_filename` instead of `env.tio`). Change `⍵` → `⍺` and then you can get rid of `'.'` too.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 39 bytes

```
my$f=".";while $f.IO.e {$f=get};say $f;
```

This works in the REPL, but it doesn't seem to work properly in TIO.

Comment: What about [`say first !*.IO.e,lines`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhLbOouERBUUvP018vVScnMy@1@P9/PS49IErNK9Mryczn0ufST8rM04/m0s/JLy7RTssvzUvhSspJzNAFEVxVYMCFqgcA) (23 bytes)?

Comment: The above probably blocks indefinitely when run on the command line, but something like `{}while ($_=get).IO.e;.say` should work.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 43 bytes

```
<?for(;file_exists($f=readline()););echo$f;
```

Run as CLI. Quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40 39</s> 37 bytes

```ruby
{}while File.exist? gets.chomp
$><<$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v7q2PCMzJ1XBDUjopVZkFpfYK6SnlhTrJWfk5xZwqdjZ2KjE//@vx6UHRKl5ZXolmflc@lz6SZl5@tFc@jn5xSXaafmleSlcUEkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 67 bytes

```
val f={var s="."
while(java.io.File(s).exists()){s=readLine()!!}
s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUsxDsIwENvvFWmnRIjLjtSViY2RKVXT9iBcUJIGpKpvDwExIdmWLds3nxxxGRcWd0MsswkmTKIyHsQ5BeJJiRUe1STHcpRKwVaycWLs1joWsWuxhedMzsqryQbJ4/ETokL7ophivayxC9YMJ2IrVdNsELdSELDCcsZEHjTonvgr@gLa@Zh2o194gN6Zef@R3@avRnwD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 35 bytes

```
{While[FileExists[x:=Prompt[]],0]x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYexCoAgFAB3f6XwNQeONbc1PByslB6URr5CiL7dhOA47gyzmVebXavyM660WeyLukSRI6ZWDWfYD0at60anNw8neUZXPkshC9bfkikIEDCRBxSwhciVC5df/oa/TXTLBw)

### Alternative solutions

**35 bytes:** `{If[FileExists[x:=Prompt[]],$[],x]}`, recursive function.

**37 bytes:** `{NestWhile[p:=Prompt,p[],FileExists]}`, iterative function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Min](https://min-lang.org), 38 bytes

```
"." :a (a exists?) ("" ask @a) while a
```

Leaves last entered filename on the stack.

### Explanation

```
"."         ; Put . on the stack. Every directory should contain this...
:a          ; Assign to a
(a exists?) ; A quot that checks if a exists in current directory
("" ask @a) ; Read line from stdin, assign to a
while       ; Do the second quote while the first leaves true on the stack
a           ; Leave a on the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 27 bytes

```
INPUT S$EXEC!CHKFILE(S$)?S$
```